# Transformer Rating Calculation

Tags: power, transformer

[image]

I am confused with the above problem. If I connect all 3 windings additively, I will get 3V1/3V2. But, I don't think there will be any change in kVA rating. It should still remain Q. The answer given in my workbook is option A. Please help me with this problem.

EDIT: It is not a homework problem. I am preparing for an exam called GATE(Graduate Aptitude Test in Engg). It is a previously asked problem in the exam.

Comment: What was explained in your lecture / notes / handouts?

Comment: No, it was not taught in the class. I came across this problem while practising.

Comment: So check the text book - as you mention it is an aptitude test...

Comment: Only answers are mentioned not any solution or explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for sometime, I have figured out that the only way it makes sense is when I consider the ratings are each winding and not for the 3 phase transformer.

Each winding is rated Q kVA and V1/V2

Now when you connect three windings additively, you get a single phase transformer with rating 3V1/3V2 and 3Q kVA